# Change async series order if callback error

Tags: node.js

```
    async.series([
        function(callback){
            data.exists(user, callback)
        },
        function(callback){
            period.refresh(user, callback)
        }
    ],
    function(err, results){
        if(err) {

            async.series([
                function(callback){
                    data.generate(user, callback)
                },
                function(callback){
                    period.refresh(user, callback)
                }
            ])

        }
    })
```

Is there a smarter way to handle this with async? If the data exists it should be refreshe,
else it should be generated an refreshed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a series you could use a 3 step waterfall and just check for the user in the second step.

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    /* get user */
    callback(null, user);
  },
  function(user, callback) {
    if(user) return callback(null, user); // return early if user exists
    /* create user */
    callback(null, user);
  },
  function(user, callback) {
    /* refresh user */
    callback();
  }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    /* process done successfully */
  }
);
```